# Jenkins X use secrets in Preview environments

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-x

I'm using Jenkins X for microservice build / deployment. In each environment there are shared secrets used across microservices (client keys etc) which are injected into `deployment.yaml` as environment variables using `valueFrom` and `secretKeyRef`. This works well in Production and Staging where the namespaces are well know, but since preview generates a new namespace each time, these secrets will no exist. Is there a way to copy secrets from another, known, namespace, or a better approach?

Answer (score 4):

You can create another namespace called `jx-preview` to store preview specific secrets, and add this line after the `jx preview` command in your Jenkinsfile

`sh "kubectl get secret {secret_name} --namespace={from_namespace} --export -o yaml | kubectl apply --namespace=jx-$ORG-$PREVIEW_NAMESPACE -f -"`

Not sure if this is the best way though

Answer (score 0):

We've got a command to service [link services](https://jenkins-x.io/developing/preview/#adding-more-resources) from one namespace to another - such as to link services from staging to your preview environment via [jx step link services](https://jenkins-x.io/commands/jx_step_link/).

It would be nice to add a similar command to copy secrets from a namespace in the same way. I've raised [an issue to track this new feature](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/3266)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create your own Job in `charts/preview/templates/myjob.yaml` and in that job create whatever Secrets you need however you want and then annotate it so that its triggered as a post-install hook of your Preview chart